# Help on parse JSON and show results (Android)

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

I created a  JSON file and I uploaded on a domain, my goal is to parse that document e get back the informations but I do something wrong, this is my JSON file:

```
{
    "Show" : {
        "id" : "abcde123",
        "name" : "Traviata",
        "date" : "September 15, 2011"
    }
}
```

This is the Java code that I use to parse the JSON:

```
private void parse(){
    try {

        URL eventsJSON = new URL("http://www.site.com/test/sample.json");
        URLConnection tc = eventsJSON.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(line);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                eventsJSONObject = (JSONObject) jArray.get(i);

            }
        }

        JSONArray eventsArray = eventsJSONObject.getJSONArray("Show");

    //name of the show
    Log.d("LOG", jArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("name").toString());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the class isn't working.. can someone help me please? 
Thanks!!!! :)

**EDIT:**
This is a working code, but I can't make it work parsing the JSON from a file

```
 String jString = "{\"Show\" : {\"from\" : \"June 12, 2011\",\"id\" : \"abcde123\",\"name\" : \"Traviata\"}}";


 JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jString);
 JSONObject eventsObject = jObject.getJSONObject("Shows");

 String eventId = eventsObject.getString("id");
 String eventName = eventsObject.getString("name");
 String eventDateFrom = eventsObject.getString("from");
```

how do I implement the buffered reader and memorize the JSON code in the jString String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
JSONArray eventsArray = eventsJSONObject.getJSONArray("Show");
```

should be parsed as JSONObject:

```
JSONObject eventObj = eventsJSONObject.getJSONOnject("Show");
```

Rest should be simple. "show" represents an object with 3 fields, not an array.

BTW, an array would look like that:

```
{
    "Show" : [
        "id" : "abcde123",
        "name" : "Traviata",
        "date" : "September 15, 2011"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you please try editing my code? I still cant make it work

Comment: An editing won't really help you, instead - a (really) short and nice tutorial (look on the json structure there and how do they get each field): http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

Comment: Cool, thank you! The tutorial works fine but the problem is that String line is always null.. did I miswrite the while cycle?